# unable to locate package error when installing Matlab 2013a

Tags: apt, matlab

10 yesterday I downloaded matlab R2013a from university website
But it says

```
elif@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install MATHWORKS_R2013A
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package MATHWORKS_R2013A
elif@ubuntu:~$
```

I did everthing that is written in websites 
How can I fixed the problem? thanks...

Comment: post the link for the guide you follows.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get` downloads and installs packages from a package repository, and Matlab as commercial software is of course not included in those (standard) repositories.

If you have downloaded Matlab as a Debian package file (MATHWORKS_R2013A.deb), then you can use

```
sudo dpkg -i MATHWORKS_R2013A.deb
```

If the downloaded file is not a deb, you cannot install it using Ubuntu package management tools. In that case it is probably a binary installer (e.g. MATHWORKS_R2013A.sh) that has to be started as an executable. My guess:

```
sudo ./MATHWORKS_R2013A.sh
```

If none of this applies, you have to give more detailed information on what exactly you downloaded.